# Laravel Coinbase API Http exception error on live server but works on Xampp

Tags: php, laravel, api, coinbase-api

Coinbase API on Laravel generates the following **error log**. Somebody help me to solve this.This error only occurs in the live environment, but within xampp its working well. Immediate below is the error log. What could be the issue?

```
 production.ERROR: Type error: Argument 1 passed to `Coinbase\Wallet\Exception\HttpException::exceptionClass() must be an instance of Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface, null given, called in /home/amunuxwq/public_html/core/vendor/coinbase/coinbase/src/Exception/HttpException.php on line 33 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Type error: Argument 1 passed to Coinbase\\Wallet\\Exception\\HttpException::exceptionClass() must be an instance of Psr\\Http\\Message\\ResponseInterface, null given, called in /home/amunuxwq/public_html/core/vendor/coinbase/coinbase/src/Exception/HttpException.php on line 33 at /home/amunuxwq/public_html/core/vendor/coinbase/coinbase/src/Exception/HttpException.php:98)`
```

This is the code am using on the laravel project.

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Client;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Configuration;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Account;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Address;
class PayData {

    private static $apiKey= "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
    private static $apiSecret= "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY";

     public static function apiauth()
     {

        $configuration = Configuration::apiKey(self::$apiKey, self::$apiSecret);
        $client = Client::create($configuration);
        return $client;
     }

    public static function rates(){
    try{
        $xrate['usvalue']= PayData::apiauth()->getSpotPrice('BTC-USD')->getAmount();
        $xrate['buyvalue']=PayData::apiauth()->getBuyPrice('BTC-USD')->getAmount();
        $xrate['sellvalue']=PayData::apiauth()->getSellPrice('BTC-USD')->getAmount();
         return $xrate;
    }
    catch (Exception $e){
        $msg =$e->getMessage();
        return $msg;
    }
    }

    Public static function myaddress($name){
        try{

        $account =PayData::apiauth()->getPrimaryAccount();
        $address= new Address ([
            'name'=>$name
            ]);
         $add = PayData::apiauth()->createAccountAddress($account,$address);
         //$addressId=PayData::apiauth()->getAccountAddresses($account);
        //$addressd = $addressId->getfirstID();
        //$address = PayData::apiauth()->getAccountAddress($account,$addressd);
        //echo $address->getAddress();
        return $add->getAddress();
        }
        catch (Exception $e){
            report ($e);
            return false;

        }
    }


    }
```

Comment: Please show your code. An error does not help much

Comment: OK this is the code

Comment: @aynber i have included the code

Comment: How did you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your coinbase certificate (`ca-coinbase.crt`) in `etc` folder.

It will work :)

Comment: Certificate added to the etc folder but it still shows the same error message.

Comment: hello, please how to add certificate?